# update summary table from detail table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, merge

[image]I have 2 tables named as

```
PROD_DET 
( ID , PROD_SUMM_ID, TRANS_DATE,  EMP_ID,  PROC_ID ,  PCS)
```

and

```
PROD_SUMM
( ID , TRANS_DATE,  EMP_ID,  PROC_ID ,  PCS)
```

Now whenever a record is inserted into PROD_DET table,

I want to `Insert` ( if the record of a unique TRANS_DATE, EMP_ID, PROC_ID is not available) /`Update` (in case of record of a unique TRANS_DATE, EMP_ID, PROC_ID is available) in my `PROD_SUMM` table as,

1. the  unique TRANS_DATE  from PROD_DET
        table should be put into TRANS_DATE of PROD_SUMM table,
2. unique EMP_ID and unique PROC_ID  should be go  into their
   respective columns
        in PROD_SUMM table
3. sum of PCS of multiple records of a particluar TRANS_DATE  should update in
        PCS column   in PROD_SUMM table
4. ID from PROD_SUMM table  should update to PROD_SUMM_ID column in 
        PROD_DET  table

I have tried out with a trigger but, did not came to the mark,
find the screenshots below

script to crate tables 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PROD_DET](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PROD_SUMM_ID] [int] NULL,
    [TRAN_DATE] [date] NOT NULL,
    [EMP_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PROC_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PCS] [smallint] NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT [PK_PROD_DET] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
( [ID] ASC ) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PROD_SUMM](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TRAN_DATE] [date] NOT NULL,
    [EMP_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PROC_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PCS] [int] NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT [PK_PROD_SUMM] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
( [ID] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY] ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 0):

see rough work.any problem ask.

```
   Declare @tbl table([ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,[TRAN_DATE] [date] NOT NULL,[EMP_ID] [int] NOT NULL,[PROC_ID] [int] NOT NULL,[PCS] [int] NOT NULL)

insert into PROD_DET
output inserted.TRANS_DATE,  inserted.EMP_ID,  inserted.PROC_ID ,  inserted.PCS into @tbl
values() -- for PROD_DET

merge  PROD_SUMM as target
using select id,b.TRAN_DATE,b.PCS,a.EMP_ID,a.PROC_ID from @tbl a inner join
(select TRAN_DATE,sum(PCS) PCS from @tbl group by TRAN_DATE) b on a.TRAN_DATE=b.TRAN_DATE) as source
on  target.TRANS_DATE=source.TRANS_DATE and target.EMP_ID=source.EMP_ID and target.PROC_ID =source.EMP_ID
when matched then
update
 set TRAN_DATE=source.TRAN_DATE,EMP_ID=source.EMP_ID,PROC_ID=source.PROC_ID,PCS=source.PCS
when not matched then
insert (TRAN_DATE,EMP_ID,PROC_ID,PCS) 
values(source.TRAN_DATE,source.EMP_ID,source.PROC_ID,source.PCS)
```